# unable to unzip to opt directory

Tags: command-line, unzip

I'm trying to install `jstock` to the `/opt` directory. I'm getting the below error.

1. `jstock` is in the `~/Downloads` directory.
2. The file name is correct.

Kindly guide.

```
navjeet@navjeet-Lenovo-G50-80:~/Downloads$ sudo unzip jstock-1.0.7.17 bin.zip -C /opt 
[sudo] password for navjeet:  
Archive: jstock-1.0.7.17-bin.zip  
caution: filename not matched:  -C 
caution:filename not matched:  /opt 
navjeet@navjeet-Lenovo-G50-80:~/Downloads$
```

Note: bin.zip and -C are separated by space, though it looks otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Took me a few minutes to see what you were doing wrong. You are using `tar` syntax for `unzip` and they aren't compatible. You want to run this:

```
sudo unzip -d /opt/ jstock-1.0.7.17-bin.zip
```

For tar the syntax is `tar xf file.tar -C dir` whereas for unzip it's `unzip -d dir file.zip`

Comment: It worked wonders! kudos to you and thanks a lot.. Meanwhile i would like to know more about the differences of tar and unzip.

Comment: @Krishtopher can i use tar to unzip (or untar , if that sounds correct) a .zip file ?

Comment: Nope I just tested `tar` doesn't support .zip files, it does support `.tar.gz` and `.tar.bz2` files though.